# how to bulk download text files from a webpage

Tags: windows-10

I want to download all text files from this webpage...

https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/dbgap/studies/phs001672/analyses/

How can I do that and place the download in a zip file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) tool, use it to [download all the files](https://serverfault.com/q/25199/339317), then zip them yourself.

Or, you can [mount that FTP server as a drive](https://serverfault.com/q/6079/339317) in Windows, and deal with them in Explorer however you want (e.g. drag and drop them to another folder on your computer and zip them). Or don't mount directly to Windows, but use a [graphical FTP client](https://kinsta.com/blog/best-ftp-clients/) to connect to that server and then copy the files down.